# A repository with creative Forms or examples for Android

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'd like to find some software repository with examples. These examples should be creative something similar to [Zend CSS Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/). I want to use design-patterns Android applications like a Website.

Could someone tell me one website please?

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that while the market is still a bit new to have a fully-featured software repository with design patters, there are some good resources out there.  For example, here is a good resource for software examples:
http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Here is a pretty good blog that focuses on design patterns for Android:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/

Comment: +1 for androiduipatterns.com which led me to http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ - the '11 version will be out soon too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/). You can various android projects.